# D nested functions type inference

Tags: d, type-inference, nested-function

Does anyone know if subj will be implemented?
At least, auto storage class for them?
Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by subj?

Comment: I mean that constr. void foo() { auto bar() { return 3.14; }; } won't compile since bar can't have auto storage class. I was just curious if at least such enhancement is planned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various problem with auto functions in general, so it could very well be that you can't do

```
void main()
{
    auto bar() { return "hello world"; }

    writeln(bar());
}
```

because of a bug with auto rather than it being as designed. I'm not sure what the exact plans for that are, though I would *think* that you would supposed to be able to use auto as the return type of a nested function. There is an [enhancement request](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=5045) on it in either case.

However, regardless of whether auto works with nested functions, you *can* declare a delegate in a similar manner:

```
void main()
{
    auto bar = () { return "hello world"; };

    writeln(bar());
}
```

So, the basic functionality is still there, even if the exact syntax that you were looking for doesn't currently work.

Comment: If I understand correctly, delegate or function keyword isn't necessary?

Comment: It might be better to have that `const bar = ...` so that it acts more like a real function WRT lvalues.

Comment: @Target-san You usually only use the function or delegate keyword if you want to force that a lambda function be one or the other, and there's usuallly no need.

Comment: BTW, if you ommit the keyword, it will *always* be a delegate so the forcing is only one way.

Comment: I'm not sure that the spec enforces that it's always a delegate if you don't mark it as a function - in theory the compiler should be able to figure it out for you - but at present, it does always generate a delegate from what I can tell. That may change at some point though. I don't think that it's a good idea to rely on it being a delegate or a function pointer if you don't specify which it is. In most cases, though, I don't think that it matters particularly. If you really care, you can always mark it.